# Uninstalled numpy to fix something. Now after reinstall, still getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'" error

Tags: python, numpy

To fix an issue with one of my scripts, I tried this at the suggestion of this post: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1508#issuecomment-465249534

I ran

pip uninstall numpy

and then:

conda install numpy

I also checked in the Anaconda navigator that I had Numpy, and that it was the latest version. However, I still can't seem to use numpy in Python.

Comment: How are you calling python? "python", "python2" or "python3"? Please try installing it like this: "python -m pip install numpy" and check if it works.

Comment: I was having a heart attack here over having screwed up my python and possibly needing to redownload it.... how do I mark your comment as a solution?

Comment: I will add it as answer, was just checking if that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try installing it like this:

```
python -m pip install numpy
```

Where "python" should represent your python alias (Normally, this can be "python3", "python2" or "python")

This calls pip for the current Python in PATH, the same Python you are using currently.

Probably there is another Python, where the **pip** module overrides the one you want.

You can confirm this by using `where python` (for Windows) or `which python` for Linux.